# Python Request to C#

Tags: python, c#, api

I'm attempting to utilize an API call that I found in some Python code and translate it into C# so that I can integrate it into a Unity application I'm developing. The Python code is:

```
response = requests.request(
    method=method,
    url=url.as_uri(),
    verify=settings.CACERT_FILE,
    **kwargs,
)
```

where Method = POST, Verify = None, and Kwargs = {'json': {'time': 1, 'types': ['the_types']}}.

My C# implementation:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("theurl.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("{'json': {'time': 1, 'types': ['the_types']}}").Result;  
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.Log("Worked");

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Didn't work");
            }
            client.Dispose();
```

I'm quite new to C#, and I can't figure out what I'm missing or where to go from here. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Utilizing client.PostAsync

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("theUrl"), new StringContent("{'json': {'time': 1, 'types': ['the_types']}}")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're calling `GetAsync` but claim the original request was a POST request.  Aside from that, take a look at the *documentation* for the method you're calling.  `GetAsync` expects a *URL* as a string, not JSON.

Comment: So it looks like PostAsync is the way to go. Is there a correct way to go about using it? Just doing a quick search through on Stack there appears to be a bunch of different ways

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync)?  You are certainly encouraged to do so and make an attempt, addressing any errors or unexpected results in your debugging.

Comment: @David followed the documentation and a few Stack questions and ended up with what I have in my Edited question. Still not finding any success unfortunately. Response code I'm getting is `BadRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example perfectly suites your request. You can easily change HttpMethod or request content in it.

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "your url");
        message.Content = JsonContent.Create("your json content", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Also dont forget to `await` your asynchronous code (`client.PostAsync` in your example or `httpClient.SendAsync` in mine).
Also good to mention that best practice is to use `IHttpClientFactory` with custom options such a "baseUrl" or "required headers" for HttpClient declaration.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a JSON object for `{'json': {'time': 1, 'types': ['the_types']}}` C# is complaining about the `[` and `]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bob Do you want to create a class with these properties, or you want to push this string as json object?

Comment: push this string as a json object